# Join by multiple FK from one table

Tags: mysql, codeigniter-3

I tried to join by multiple fks from one table

lets say i have posts table and users table :

```
Posts
-----
id (Primary Key)
title
body
owner_id (Foreign Key)
reviewer_id (Foreign Key)
approver_id (Foreign Key)

Users
------
id (Primary Key)
name
role
```

the owner_id, reviewer_id, and approver_id are the foreign key of users.id,

I'm using CI3 by the way, and what i've done so far :

```
$this->db->select('posts.*,owner.name,reviewer.name,approver.name')
    ->from('posts')
    ->join('users as owner','posts.owner_id = owner.id')
    ->join('users as reviewer','posts.reviewer_id = reviewer.id')
    ->join('users as approver','posts.approver_id = approver.id')
    ->get()
    ->result();
```

The result is fine, but is there any other way to do this ? because it seems that too many joins have been made

Answer (score 1):

This is the way to do it.

Think of joins as between individual rows instead of between individual tables. A given row in `posts` probably matches a different row in `users` for each of those foreign keys.

[image]

The result of the join is a new row, with many columns, taken from each of those rows.

[image]

Comment: So this is the only way to do it then, but thanks for your explanation above i understand the concept